# Protoc can not be built when CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH is TRUE

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, protoc

In my project the variable is set to True. This causes the problem that protoc can not be built as a shared library.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(untitled4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "build shared libraries" ON)
option(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS "Build the static library" OFF)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        proto
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
        GIT_TAG        v21.6)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(proto)

add_executable(untitled4 main.cpp)
```

The error:

```
../../bin/protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotocd.so.32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is a **question**? The error message tells that `protoc` executable is failed to run because it doesn't find the library `libprotocd.so.32`. It is expected, since you put into the executable RPATH corresponding to the **installation path** of the library, but the library is not installed yet.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is there a possibility to cope with the problem without setting CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH to false

Comment: What exactly do you want by setting `CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` to TRUE? Do you want **all** libraries and executables in the build tree to have same RPATH as in the install tree? Or do you want that property **only** for targets created in **your project**? In the latter case you could set variable to FALSE immediately before `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` and reset to TRUE after it. That way Protobuf libraries and executables will be built as usual, using CMake-generated build RPATH, but targets in your project will have build RPATH which is specified by you for install tree.

Comment: Will not it cause problems with the proto lib after install?

Comment: The variable `CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` doesn't affect on the installed artifacts at all. If you bother only without that artifacts, then do not set the variable: that way executables and libraries in the build tree will be usable too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev if I run protoc from the working directory it is located in, everything works. But if I do it from another directory I receive the error